# Reading lines from a file in PHP

Tags: php

I'm having problems reading lines from a text file in PHP.

I have this code:

```
$a_path = "./data/answers.txt";

    $answers = fopen($a_path);

    $line_num = 1;

    while ($line = fgets($answers))
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($common_q_line_nums); $i++)
        {
            if ($line_num == (int)$common_q_line_nums[$i])
            {
                echo $line;
            }
        }
        $line_num++;
    }
```

I am using Macintosh, however I updated the php.ini file with `auto_detect_line_endings = On`

The `$common_q_line_nums` sorted array contains numbers in the range of the lines in the text file.

Any idea why I'm getting nothing back? The file is opening ok, and the `$common_q_line_nums` is good.

Appreciated, Alex

Comment: You should inspect the file a little more, I always have problems with line endings, especially when they are mixed. `var_dump()` is your friend here

Comment: @Yarek yes I will have a look, I'm beginning to think it must be that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few issues that I noticed here.

First is this line:

```
 $answers = fopen($a_path);
```

[`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen) is missing the mode parameter.  It should be:

```
$answers = fopen($a_path, 'r');
```

<strike>Next, I'm not sure if this is a problem, but it may be.  Change this:</strike>

```
while($line = fgets($answers))
```

to:

```
while(($line = fgets($answers)) !== FALSE)
```

Comment: I don't think either of these are relevant. the !== FALSE logic is unnecessary, and I believe open() defaults to mode r.

Comment: @sudowned: I said that the `!== FALSE` may not be an issue, but according to the [docs for `fopen`](http://php.net/fopen), there is no default value for the mode.

Comment: @Rocket - this got the file opening ok, but now my problem is extracting the specific lines by line number...

Comment: The docs definitely agree with you, but he says he's getting a good linecount out of the file after so it's a safe bet open has an undocumented default (which isn't terribly uncommon, PHP being... well, PHP. :))

Comment: Ah, misread where he was getting the line count.  Yes, Rocket, good catch there.  :)

Comment: Not sure how I managed to misunderstand his code so badly. Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This one is better

```
$lines = file("data/answers.txt"); // each line in one array index ($lines[0], $lines[1] etc)
```

Comment: I'm getting `count($lines) == 1` using this. Any idea why?? It should be over 4000 as it is a large file with over 4000 lines.